# When modeling a rate using Poisson regression, how can I incorporate the standard error for the rate?

Tags: standard-error, poisson-regression, measurement-error

I have a data set with age-standardized mortality rates per 100,000—along with the standard error for the rate—for all US counties. I also have various predictors, and would like to use multilevel Poisson/negative binomial regression to analyze the rates.

I've been able to estimate similar models by including the log(denominator) or log(expected deaths) as offsets, but in this instance I won't have access to these data. Instead, I'd like to model the standard error to  account for uncertainty in each of the estimated rates. How can I do this?

Comment: In Poisson models, because of the mean-variance relationship, the standard errors are just a reflection of the sample size. You will find that $\text{SE}(\text{rate}_i) = \sqrt{\text{rate}_i / \text{offset}_i}$ in a saturated model. Does that answer your question? I don't know if I can get any more detailed without knowing what you're modeling. Are these rates, for instance, an exposure or an outcome?

Comment: These are mortality rates measured in deaths per 100,000. They are also reported with SEs. I need these SEs to be incorporated into the model somehow. It's similar to meta-regression, where second-stage models incorporate the variance of effect size estimates.